# Can we update the configurations from the advance section of the Azure portal programmatically?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to call an API multiple times with the change in the configuration files. Can we do the changes in the configuration files at runtime in the code before calling the API. We cannot make the code changes in the API we are trying to call.

Comment: What configuration files are you talking about? this needs more info and some code to be able to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.